# CFURLSetResourcePropertyForKey failed when disable data backup on NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: ios, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to download image files and store in `NSDocumentDirectory`. In order to do so, I has to turn off data backup on iCloud and iTunes. Below are my codes:

```
+(void)saveData:(NSData*)thedata:(NSString*)fileName
{
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
   [fileManager createFileAtPath:localFilePath contents:thedata attributes:nil];
   //prevent files from backup on iCloud or iTune
   NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:localFilePath];
   [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:fileURL];
}
```

and for my addskipbackupattributetoitematurl:

```
+(BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL
{
   if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[fileURL path]])
   {
       NSLog(@"File %@ doesn't exist!",[fileURL path]);
       return NO;
   }
   NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];    
   if ([currSysVer isEqualToString:@"5.0.1"])
   {
       const char* filePath = [[fileURL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
       const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
       u_int8_t attrValue = 1;
       int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
       NSLog(@"Excluded '%@' from backup",fileURL);
       return result == 0;
   }
   else if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
   {
       NSError *error = nil;
       BOOL result = [fileURL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
       if (result == NO)
       {
           NSLog(@"Error excluding '%@' from backup. Error: %@",fileURL, error);
           return NO;
       }
       else
       { 
           NSLog(@"Excluded '%@' from backup",fileURL);
           return YES;
       }
   }
   else
   {
       return YES;
   }
}
```

However, the `BOOL result = [fileURL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];` created the following message

> CFURLSetResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed this URL which has no scheme: /var/mobile/Applications/CF69D567-1D37-4053-BFA8-5D0FCBD9C2B2/Documents/coffee.jpg

I'm just wondering if any encountered this problem??

Comment: Hell with apple... they don't even return an error on this and the result will be YES.
But this will not set the "ExcludedFromBackupKey".
They rejected me twice for this :(

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Solved. once I changed

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:localFilePath];
```

to

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localFilePath];
```

everything work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**:

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: somepath)
```

Answer (score -1):

The designated method for creating a local file's url is : `NSURL * __url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:__path isDirectory:NO];`
It works perfectly.
Good luck!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34913688)