# CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because passed URL no scheme

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I have a program that saves a file to the iCloud and this has worked great for iOS7, but now I get this error with iOS8 and cannot seem to find the answer on how to fix it. Anyone else had this problem? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**The Error:**
CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed this URL which has no scheme: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ASFHDDE3-B1BB-41D7-A47C-DCC328362W21/Documents/mypictostore.png

**The Line of Code Throws Error:**
[fileManager setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:backupUrl destinationURL:[[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents" isDirectory:true] URLByAppendingPathComponent:backupName] error:&theError];

**URLS:**
destinationURL: file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/ABC23455~MY-Program/
backupUrl: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ASDFGEEW-B1BB—6FR6-A47C-DCCF21876D36/Documents/mypic.png

Thank you,
Jon

Comment: I fixed this by appending file:/// to the front of the url string. I am posting the solution so others may find it if they are having the same problem.

Comment: Try using [NSURL fileURLWithPath:<your-path-here>]; instead

Comment: I had a similar issue to @Jon I was pulling images from gstatic.com which has no scheme. I solved it by adding an "http://" to the front of the url string.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

For me this problem was fixed by adding

```
file://
```

right before the file path address like this:

```
var filePath = "file://\(fileURLpath)"
```

Answer (score 24):

Or maybe you can use `NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mypictostore", ofType: "png")!)` instead of using `NSURL(string: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mypictostore", ofType: "png")!)`

Comment: add "file:///" in front of your path

Comment: @pranavjayadev I think using fileURLWithPath is more appropriate.

Answer (score 15):

Look this link for Objective-c answer: [CFURLSetResourcePropertyForKey failed when disable data backup on NSDocumentDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928509/cfurlsetresourcepropertyforkey-failed-when-disable-data-backup-on-nsdocumentdire)

Older Swift version answer:

```
var str:String = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3039975A-5E05-4A4C-8000-55C681A7C35F/Documents/index.html"

var url:URL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: str)
```

Swift 4 Answer:

```
var str:String = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3039975A-5E05-4A4C-8000-55C681A7C35F/Documents/index.html"

var url:URL = URL(string: str)!
```

Answer (score 9):

### Depending on what you need to do with the path, you may need to prepend the scheme **file://**. See more at [documentation/foundation/url](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url)

If you need the **file path**, use **fileURLWithPath**:

```
let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath)
```

it will give you the path as

*file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7C1D854B-8A2E-4FF0-BD30-0652AEE10B6F/Documents/image_8ZMAM.jpg*

---

If you need the **path** without the scheme, use **string**:

```
let imageURL = URL(string: imagePath)
```

it will give you the path as

*/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7C1D854B-8A2E-4FF0-BD30-0652AEE10B6F/Documents/image_8ZMAM.jpg*

Answer (score 7):

look, I find this,The `url` is `The location to write the data into`. we should tell the system a `file path`.

- var filePath = "file://(fileURLpath)"
- var url:URL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: fileURLpath)

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGKxV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this, I think the following code is great as if you are not sure any particular url is correct or not for the CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey

```
if testURL.isFileURL == false {

    testURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: testURL.absoluteString)

}
```

Answer (score -2):

`var url = USL(fileUrlWithString: "/private/var/...")`

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.